# Python data cleaning

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where all the values are under one particular column. How would I assign the values to each column. below is the screenshot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrjx9.png)

Kindly suggest. Thanks Chethan

Comment: welcome to so.  2 suggestions. first, to avoid those downvotes try and include some of your code instead of a link to a screen shot...and perhaps a small snip of the file you are trying to import. and second, if an answer solves your problem it is customary to "accept" it so that the question can be seen as dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a delimiter issue...

in your pandas.read_csv command...if you're using pandas, try sep=';' as an argument.

```
pandas.read_csv(yourfile, sep=';')
```

see docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html